# CakePHP Routing Best Practice (Removing all Default Routes)

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

Is this the best practice for removing all default routes in CakePHP?

```
Router::connect('/**');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the following line in your routes.php

```
// load the CakePHP default routes (i.e. /controller/action/id)
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have fully customized all your routes, and want to avoid any possible duplicate content penalties from search engines, you can remove the default routes that CakePHP offers by deleting them from your application’s routes.php file.

This will cause CakePHP to serve errors, when users try to visit urls that would normally be provided by CakePHP but have not been connected explicitly.

For more reference

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I have removed all default routes in routes.php, but I can still access a controller (/scores/view). How do I block that route explicitly without using the above code?